# How to deleterows from one table depending on values from other table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

TABLE I.

```
columns : A B C D

values:   a b c d         
          q w e r
```

TABLE II

```
C: A B C D E
V: a b c d e
```

On both the tables A, B ,C ,D Define one row (primary key).

Now i need to delete rows from TABLE I when in TABLE II E=e (obviously the mapping betwwen two tables is on A, B, C ,D).

I need to perform the this in one query only. Please.

I tried :
**DELETE FROM TABLE I WHERE (A,B,C,D) in(SELECT A,B,C,D FROM TABLE II WHERE E='e')**

Is this correct??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join both tables even in `DELETE` statements, eg.

```
DELETE a
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.A = b.A
  AND a.B = b.B
  AND a.C = b.C
  AND a.D = b.D
WHERE b.E = 'e'
```

Comment: When we take the innerJoin ... we can still fire such statements which will effect the original tables permanently??

Comment: Just curious, why do you have such massive indentation? I've never seen anyone since Margret Thatcher go so far to the right.

Comment: I can't understand your question but this basically removes a record from `Table1` which the records exists on `Table2` and delete only if `Table2.E = 'e'`.

Comment: @Bohemian Good question and the third person to ask. I don't know but I'm used to with doing it `:D`. One `TAB` after keyword. Align joins with tables and align conditions on `ON` clause. hehe

Comment: My question is that dont the joins give us in result a view??

Comment: @BhumiSinghal no, it doesn't give you a view. Let me ask you this, do you really want to delete records from table1 permanently or just create a view that hides any particular record which value for `Table2.E = 'e'`?

Comment: I favour simple left aligning everything, ie INNER at far left, because it is really just another FROM. I also favour same-line ON if it fits, or if not i do what you do. But I've never understood left aligning the *second* word of lines - that make no sense whatsoever! It's whacky to say the least. Haven't you noticed that you're one of the few people left who carry the flame for this insane formatting? It might be time to join the land of the sane. Would you like me to edit your SQL so it's readable? (Recall that clarity and readability are the essence of good programming)

Comment: @Bohemian do me a favor to modify my code alignment so I can leave the people who carries flame from insane formatting. `:D`

Comment: I see now what you're doing with that 2nd word align thing. I want you to go to the tool box, get a screwdriver and pry off the tab key. Just use a space! But seriously, one *important* difference is putting the logical operators (AND/OR) at the *start* of the line; when at the end their lack of prominence could lead to bugs - the operator is a natural trigger for a newline (there they are really just another WHERE). Cheers ;-)

Comment: @Bohemian thanks for that. hehe let me study this new formatting and slowly adapt from it since I'm used to press the `TAB` key` :D

Comment: Oh, I almost forgot... +1 !  :)

Comment: Btw I didn't even mention the whole uppercase thing. I believe that the only reason SQL keywords are often in caps is because when the language was created, most computers didn't have lowercase letters. If you're feeling really bold, go lowercase too! While you have the screwdriver out, also pry off the SHIFT key! I always use lowercase, again for clarity: it has been proven that words in lowercase are more quickly and easily comprehended than all-caps words. I didn't go so far as to make that edit too - I don't want to cause you too much shock :)

Comment: Tempted to downvote. `INNER JOIN` is not another `FROM`. `AND`s and `OR`s are not another `WHERE`.

Comment: @JW - This does not work on web sql ...:( It gives we a sytax error

Comment: could not prepare statement (1 near "a": syntax error)
I am performing this on webSQL provided by HTML 5

Comment: if i do SELECT * FROM FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b
  ON a.A = b.A
  AND a.B = b.B
  AND a.C = b.C
  AND a.D = b.D
WHERE b.E = 'e'   it works

Comment: I guess there is some issue with using delete with joins in web-sql/sqllite. So +1 and the acceptance.